# object arranging in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

here is  my dictionary and its values

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDic=[NSMutableDictionary Dictionary];
[myDIC setObject:@""];

[myDIC  setObject:string1 forKey:key1];
[myDIC  setObject:string2 forKey:key2];
[myDIC  setObject:string3 forKey:key3];
```

so up to here i have filled up my dictionary.now i want to read them through a for loop.

```
for (NSString *key in myDic ){


}
```

here is my problem! inside this loop the my first key will be **key1** but i seems it start from the last key that i have set before!

is there anyone who can tell me why ? and how i can meet my expectation as what i explained?

Comment: There is no guarantee that the first or the last entry will be the one you get. Even if you try NSEnumeration, the same behavior applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSDictionary is not an index base collection it's a Hashtable, and like all HashTable, the elements are store according to some logic base on some Hash that you don't know. If you look in the documentation for NSDictionary you will find a sentence that state that there is not guaranty about the order into which the item will be retrieve.
If you want your key to be retrieve in a specific order you will need to keep your keys in an NSArray, in the order that you want them.

---

Or you can sort your keys when you need them.

```
NSArray * allKeys = [myDict allKeys];
allKeys = [allKeys sortedArrayUsing//  [see the documentation for all options][1] ];
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem before. The order of a specific element in NSArray of NSMutableArray is decided by its index.

But unlike NSArray or NSMutableArray,The elements order in NSMutableDictionary or NSDictionary is undefined and nobody knows because its mechanism.
I chose a paragraph from Mac OS X Developer Libary for you:

> "Internally, a dictionary uses a hash table to organize its storage
>   and to provide rapid access to a value given the corresponding key.
>   However, the methods defined for dictionaries insulate you from the
>   complexities of working with hash tables, hashing functions, or the
>   hashed value of keys. The methods take keys directly, not in their
>   hashed form."